# Waitforsingleobject works when trying to open Notepad++ but returns immediately with Firefox

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, waitforsingleobject

I have the following code that opens an application using CreateProcess and waits for it for a few seconds and then closes it if its not been closed. The same code works OK on notepad++ for example, but not when I try to open Firefox.exe

```
BOOL CALLBACK SendWMCloseMsg(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //never gets called when opening Firefox.exe
    DWORD dwProcessId = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwProcessId);
    if (dwProcessId == lParam)
        SendMessageTimeout(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 30000, NULL);
    return TRUE;
}


int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO         si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));

    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    WCHAR szFilename[] = L"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";
    if (CreateProcess(NULL,
        szFilename,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        FALSE,
        CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &si,
        &pi))
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

        auto a = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 30000);
        if (a == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
        {
            EnumWindows(&SendWMCloseMsg, pi.dwProcessId);
            if (WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
            {
                //never gets here.
                TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
            }
        }

        //a vlaue is 0 and it never gets in the if statement.
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`SendWMCloseMsg` does not get called and when I remove the if statement and call `EnumWindows(&SendWMCloseMsg, pi.dwProcessId);`, it still does not find the correct processId.

What Am I doing wrong with this code and how to address this issue?

I'm using Windows 10, 64bit and VS2015

Comment: Browsers are complex beasts these days. They aren't simple single process apps like Notepad++. They use separate processes to isolate tabs so that crashes in one tab don't bring the entire browser down. Have a look in task manager when your browser is running to see how many different instances of the process there are. In other words, your code will need to be modified to match the browser's process model.

Comment: Firefox, like any browser, is a single-instance app.  If you start it again then it notices that it is already running, uses process interop to tell the first instance what URL to open.  And quits.  [Look here](https://superuser.com/questions/1202422/how-do-i-run-two-copies-of-firefox) for a possible solution, also the place to ask for help about this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I get that, but how can I use CreateProcess to get any help regarding the newly created instance of FF. or this approach is wrong one? and if so, what do u suggest?

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for the comment, but I dont want to start a new copy of FF, just to get the handle of the instance that was started with the CreateProcess call :)

Comment: Well, you did.  And you correctly detected that it terminated.  It works, congratulations.  What it is supposed to accomplish is something that nobody can see.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Probably your approach is wrong, but of course we don't actually know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: No it does not terminate the process!, otherwise i would not have posted this question in the first place!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what I have is a desktop application that controls [opens/resizes/moves/closes] other windows applications (i.e. FF, Notepad++, IE, ...etc). for most of the applications I have this approach works OK, for some including FF, Chrome. the actual code instead of trying to terminate the process gets the windows handles to it but its the same approach.

Comment: @user3113652 "*No it does not terminate the process!, otherwise i would not have posted this question in the first place!*" - yes, the process **that you launch** terminates immediately, that is why `WaitForSingleObject()` exits immediately. But that does not guarantee that **the process you see onscreen** is **the same process you launch**. It is likely **not the same process** at all.

Comment: I upvoted, because I think downvoting this question is mean.  It's a reasonable thing to ask and the OP did his best.  Lighten up guys.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that the process you started with `CreateProcess` created a bunch of other processes - and then quit.

Your `WaitForSingleObject` completes successfully, and your program ends.

Comment: "*created a bunch of other processes*" - in which case, you have to create a [job object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161.aspx) to keep track of them all. Look at [How do I wait until all processes in a job have exited?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130405-00/?p=4743) on Raymond Chen's blog on MSDN.

Comment: @Martin Bonner: that was short and understandable.