# How to get real ID of the process spawned by CreateProcess

Tags: c++, pid, createprocess

I'm spawning calc.exe by CreateProcess:

```
CreateProcess(pathToCalc, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

then I need to find hWND of the calculator dialog window. To find it I use

```
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsCallback, pi.dwProcessId);
```

But it never finds hWND. After investigation it appeared that calc.exe spawns different aplication `win32calc.exe` and it has different PID (not he one in pi.dwProcessId)

how to get PID of `win32calc.exe` or/and hWND of it's window please?

Windows 10. Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Check your `pi` argument. It should contain everything you need to know about the new process. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684873(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `pi` has PID of calc.exe but when I do EnumWindows it can't find calc.exe since it is already closed. So I need to find PID of `win32calc.exe`

Comment: Perhaps you should just launch `win32calc.exe`...

Comment: it was an example, windows has a number of such apps. So this can't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327232/waitforsingleobject-works-when-trying-to-open-notepad-but-returns-immediately

Comment: This was the traditional code to kick the tires on EnumWindows and friends.  It however does not work anymore on Win10, the calculator app is now a UWP app.  Which has a *very* different way of creating the window, its main window is a child of the UWP desktop host.  You can still kick by using Notepad instead.

Comment: Different case, I need to find PID or hWND of the subproccess which is running.
@HansPassant can you explain in more details please or give some code example please?

Comment: Hard to give you more details when you don't give more details.  You already get the PID back from CreateProcess, last argument.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes I get this PID but it is for `calc.exe` but the window it opens belongs to a different application `win32calc.exe`. So I need somehow to find the PID of that application and have no idea how.

Comment: Didn't find any better solution then take process snapshot and iterate through all of them with checking parent PID